# Capturing End User detail in an Oracle DB via Connection Pool in Websphere

Tags: oracle, security, websphere, audit

I am currently working on an auditing piece where I need to know the end user name in the Oracle database in the background.

The application uses Oracle authentication to grant access, and to handle permissions on features in the application.  It also (correctly) handles access to underlyinig data, ensuring the end user credentials persist into the data layer.

When I try to audit the application (using Oracle auditing) I only get the connection pool user ID and the Websphere server name.

I have searched and found suggestions to use Reauthentication (which doesn't log the correct user ID until the connection pool is fully used), WAS.clientinfo (which plain ol' doesn't pass the end user credentials to the DB) and have found reference to Guardium (which does the job, but is hideously expensive.)

How can I pass end user information to the data layer?  I don't mind if this comes down to a configuration change, or a 3rd party product; as long as it works we can assess it.

Comment: By Oracle Authentication, do you mean OID? It looks to me as an Application issue, since we have a couple of Applications that behaves the same way and we have OID for Authentication, and we were not able to capture the userid for auditing. The apps are built on JavaEE (Swing) and run on OC4J instances. Even though OID has its own DB for authentication it necessarily doesn't mean that the user id will persist on the Applications data layer and I am not sure if there is a way at all to achieve this.

Comment: If you can setup all end users as database users Oracle's proxy authentication sounds like something you could use. Check out the manual for details (or search for "oracle proxy authentication")

Comment: User management is done on the Oracle database.  I'm looking at Oracele Proxy Authentication just now.  Will post my findings later.  Annjawn, the application authenticates the user using normal Oracle authentication, not OID.

Comment: The only thing I've managed to find that seems to do the job is Guardium (http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/guardium/)  If you follow the link (or search for Guardium in Google) you can get the pricing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0506_barghouthi/0506_barghouthi.html

This is a old one but i guess most of the contents are still valid today

HTH

Comment: Thanks, I have looked at this before, but it looks like the connection pool must be fully utilised before the connection is reauthenticated. As an audit tool this is not an ideal solution, but we're on the right lines.

Answer (score 0):

Reauthentication does not happen on first connection indeed.
However, when implementing your DataStoreHelper that extends Oracle11gDataStoreHelper you are required to implement two methods:

1. doConnectionSetupPerTransaction which is called on reauthentication.
2. doConnectionSetup which is called on first connection.

In both you can call WSSubject.getCallerPrincipal() to get current application user. Then, you may use conn.unwrap(OracleConnection.class).setEndToEndMetrics() API.

If using Oracle 12c database and JDBC driver, you can use Connection.setClientInfo instead of OracleConnection.setEndToEndMetrics.